# What mathematical method should I use when I want to sum the result of an equation on a range of numbers?

Tags: calculus

I have a very simple equation which I need to do on a range of numbers as following:

```
(x/min)+(x/(min+1))+(x/(min+2))+...++(x/(max))
```

I have a variable called `x` which needs to be divided to a range of numbers from `min` to `max` and get the result of the addition of all the equations.

Currently I'm using a loop and it's working fine, but I am wondering how a similar problem is being solved with a single equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that $min$ and $max$ are natural numbers, the formula you seek is
$$x(H_{max}-H_{min-1})$$
where $H_n$ denotes the $n$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), defined as $H_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$.

If an approximation is good enough, $H_n\approx \ln n$, so a decent approximation to your desired sum is $$x(\ln max - ln(min -1))= x \ln \frac{max}{min -1}$$

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the 'ln' part is? Is it the base 10 logarithm?

Comment: @RojanGh.  The $\ln$ is the natural logarithm, the log to the base $e$.  A better approximation to the harmonic numbers adds $\gamma \approx 0.577$ but that subtracts out when you subtract two of them.

Comment: So for a variable of x=100, min=5 and max=20, I have to write something like: x*ln(20/4) => x*ln(5)?
The answer to this turns out as approximately 161 while the loop outputs approximately 151.
Is the difference because of the approximation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The difference is because of the approximation.  $4$ is very small; $H_4=2.0833\ldots$ while $\ln 4+\gamma=1.963\ldots$.  Try min=100 and max=200 for a closer estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However the actual minimum and maximum values are between 4 to 64 in my case and it's the x which varies. Is there any modification to the formula which can make it more accurate to work with smaller numbers?

Comment: Sure, just compute $H_4$ through $H_{64}$ and store them.  Then the formula is exact.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Putting your formula into a more mathematical format,  you say you want to compute
$$
\frac{x}{min} + \frac{x}{min+1} + \frac{x}{min+2} + \cdots + \frac{x}{max}
$$
which makes sense if $min$ and $max$ are both integers.
(Actually it makes sense as long as the difference $max - min$ is an integer.)

But
\begin{multline}
\frac{x}{min} + \frac{x}{min+1} + \frac{x}{min+2} + \cdots + \frac{x}{max} \\
= x \left(\frac{1}{min} + \frac{1}{min+1} + \frac{1}{min+2}
      + \cdots + \frac{1}{max} \right).
\end{multline}

So if you find that you have to compute the sum for many different values of $x,$ but the same values of $min$ and $max$ each time,
compute the part in the parentheses first, store it, and use it as a multiplier for each value of $x.$

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Although, the other answer is the more informative one which I chose as the answer to my question, I'm upvoting your answer too as a thank you. :)

Comment: I would pick the other answer too. Caching values of $H_n$ will allow you to easily deal with the case where $min$ and $max$ sometimes change too.